# java.lang.numberformatexception: invalid long:""

Tags: java, android

> Firstly I want to connect WebServis has parameters(identification number,name,surname,date of birth).But I can't resolve this error.

```
EditText txtTC;
EditText txtAd;
EditText txtSoyad;
EditText txtDogumYili;
Button btnDogrula;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txtTC=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtTC);
    txtAd=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtAd);
    txtSoyad=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtSoyad);
    txtDogumYili=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDogum);
    btnDogrula=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDogrula);



    btnDogrula.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
```

> Inputs that is taked from user in this class is embed in tcKnoInput

```
            final TCKimlikNoInput tcKnoInput=new TCKimlikNoInput();
            tcKnoInput.setTcKimlikNo(Long.parseLong(txtTC.getText().toString()));
            tcKnoInput.setAd(txtAd.getText().toString());
            tcKnoInput.setSoyad(txtSoyad.getText().toString());
            tcKnoInput.setDogumYili(Integer.parseInt(txtDogumYili.getText().toString()));

            TCKimlikAsyncTask lt=new TCKimlikAsyncTask();

            try{

                lt.input=tcKnoInput;
                lt.execute("");}
            catch(NumberFormatException ex){ // handle your exception
                ex.printStackTrace();

        }
    }});

    TCKimlikNoInput tcKnoInput=new TCKimlikNoInput();
    tcKnoInput.setTcKimlikNo(Long.parseLong(txtTC.getText().toString()));
    tcKnoInput.setAd(txtAd.getText().toString());
    tcKnoInput.setSoyad(txtSoyad.getText().toString());
    tcKnoInput.setDogumYili(Integer.parseInt(txtDogumYili.getText().toString()));

}
```

> thanks for answer.But I have new error at other class.Class' code is below

```
public class TCKimlikAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

public TCKimlikNoInput input;
public boolean sonuc=false;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    WebServiceCaller i=new WebServiceCallerImpl();
    sonuc=i.TcKimlikNoDogrula(input);

    return "";
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
```

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Dogrulama Sonucu:"+sonuc, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

```
}

private Context getApplicationContext() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}}
```

> then error;

java.lang.NullPointerException at onPostExecute is in this class

> for last error,Infact I shouldn't have created getApplicationContext(),but it is not seen  defined at parser

Comment: You should post a stack trace.

Comment: So, some of your `Long` parsing takes an empty input. Find it and correct it.

Comment: **An empty string is not a number**. It won't be interpreted as a 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because some of the input may be empty and you'r trying to parse it in Long. So before parse it just check your string value

```
String kimlikNo = txtTC.getText().toString().trim();
if(!kimlikNo.equalsIgnoreCase("")|| !TextUtils.isEmpty(kimlikNo))
{
tcKnoInput.setTcKimlikNo(Long.parseLong(kimlikNo));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try like this,

```
String kimlikNo = txtTC.getText().trim();
if(!kimlikNo.isEmpty())
{
   tcKnoInput.setTcKimlikNo(Long.parseLong(kimlikNo.toString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

EditText txtTC add in xml inputType="number"

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/edittext_tc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of directly parsing the "txtTC.getText().toString()" to "long type, First try to check if the EditText is not empty, Then parse it to long.
because you cant parse a blank string to long type.

replace

```
tcKnoInput.setTcKimlikNo(Long.parseLong(txtTC.getText().toString()));
```

with

```
String kimlikNo = txtTC.getText().toString().trim();
if(!kimlikNo.isEmpty())
{
   tcKnoInput.setTcKimlikNo(Long.parseLong(kimlikNo));
}
```